# multiple requests at the same time

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a problem with C# async and await when multiple requests hit my controller at the same time.
I need to requests execute one by one not all at the same time.
When the first request save data in DB then from queue get the next request

Comment: Sounds like you need to put a queue or similar in between the requests and the controller. You could also use a semaphore (google-able term) to limit a code block to one thread. I'd use a queue.

Comment: Why do you need requests to be executed sequentially? Most databases handle multiple concurrent queries just fine.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? Limiting your ASP.NET server to one request at a time is almost certainly the wrong solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's enough to put some synchronziation there. Let's assume following code:

```
public async Task GetData()
{
    var result = await db.GetDataFromDatabase();
    return result;
}
```

You can declare private field of type `SemaphoreSlim` for example:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _getDataSem = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
```

and then modify body of the method:

```
public async Task GetData()
{
    _getDataSem.Wait();
    try
    {
        var result = await db.GetDataFromDatabase();
        return result;
    }
    finally { _getDataSem.Release(); }
}
```

There is wide range of ways to synchronize such code, like `Semaphore`, `lock`s, etc.

Comment: This is a simple implementation where the order is not taken into account. So the order in which the calls are executed is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Stefan Correct, but OP did not specify that in the question.

Comment: Agree. Just to clarify for the OP. I voted -up your post